# Use Linq let sum to calculate an average

Tags: c#, linq

How to calculate sum of timedifference and average using linq let method, I tried below mentioned code it's return timedifference list   only.

```
var query1 = from c in DBCollection.Find(Query_Collection).ToList()
let DtCreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(c["CreatedDate"]) 
let DtModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(c["LastModifiedDate"]) 
let difference = (DtModifiedDate - DtCreateDate).TotalSeconds select new { difference };
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing the following:

```
var query1 = from c in DBCollection.Find(Query_Collection).ToList()
                     let DtCreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(c["CreatedDate"])
                     let DtModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(c["LastModifiedDate"])
                     let difference = (DtModifiedDate - DtCreateDate).TotalSeconds
                     let averageSum = (((DtCreateDate + DtModifiedDate) / 2) + difference) //calculate the average
                     select new { difference, averageSum };
```

Above, the 'difference' between two given dates is saved in the variable difference.
I have added another variable called 'averageSum', that now stores the value of the average between the two dates, and then adds the difference to the average.

Comment: In above code return average for every difference value, but how to find sum(total value) of difference and sum of average.

Comment: @Ezhumalai I have updated my answer, I think that should give you the result you are looking for

Comment: sorry i m not expect this, i need selected value return as sum(difference). its return single integer value.

Comment: i tried this method but not working,                                                     
     select new
                             {
                                 tot = g.Sum(q => g.Key.difference)
                             };

Answer (score 0):

I've don't understund how you calculate average for every row, but to accumulate custom values you can use Aggregate method as shown below:

```
var query1 = from c in DBCollection.Find(Query_Collection).ToList()
.Select(e => new {DtCreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(e["CreatedDate"]), DtModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(e["LastModifiedDate"])})
.Select(e => new {Diff = (e.DtModifiedDate - e.DtCreateDate).TotalSeconds, Av = 0 /* Calculate average for the row */} )
.Aggregate(new {Diff = (double) 0, Av = 0}, (group, cur) => new {Diff = group.Diff + cur.Diff, Av = group.Av + cur.Av});
```

Result of the statement is a single object which contais sums for difference and average on the whole list